# Gradle: How to set main module in multimodules project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project.

```
+ Project
++ [Android module]
++ [Java application module]
```

Java module is the main module and android is submodule which use the source from Java module.

**Settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Project'
include "androidmodule"
include "javamodule"
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "java"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

sourceSets {
    javamodule {
        java {
            srcDirs 'javamodule'
            exclude "androidmodule"
        }
    }
    androidmodule {
        java {
            srcDirs 'androidmodule'
            include 'javamodule/java/core'
        }
    }
}

compileJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

Problem: After gradle sync and build I see that Java module sources are marked as Android module, so IntelliJ sees that Main class of Java module belongs to android module.

How to set Java module as the main?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-122904.

Comment: Why does your root project apply the Java plugin and define source sets? Also, these source sets seem to include sources from the modules.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I think your answer helped me. Thank you!

Comment: @lu.koerfer, I posted not full code.